# How to debug curl access denied?

Tags: curl

I am using curl to search artifacts from Artifactory, like this:

```
curl -s -u user:passwd http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/api/search/gavc?a=8710&v=REL-0041-20181219.003944-userdebug&c=fastboot | /usr/bin/jq -r .results[].uri
```

But it shows access denied error

```
[1] 25600
[2] 25601
[2]+  Done v=REL-0041-20181119.003944-userdebug
Access denied
```

[access denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r9mk.png)

I have no idea how to debug this problem, give me some idea please.

curl version: 7.47.0

Comment: try `curl -s -u user:passwd "http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/api/search/gavc?a=8710&v=REL-0041-20181219.003944-userdebug&c=fastboot"` first, your command is not correctly escaped

Comment: Still access denied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's several different questions.

1. Your uri is not escaped so [1][2][2]+ messages means `&` treated as background execution, you need to quote uri with `""`
2. You use `-s` which means silent, so error messages are suppressed.  Please remove -s and see what error curl encountered, solve them, and then you add back jq command.
3. If your problem is essentially artifactory usage, you can add artifactory to your title.

Comment: I tried `curl -v -u user:passwd "url"`, it prints more log and seems like this problem caused by proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue.

Using the -v parameter i see that proxy -is- used even though localhost 
should -not- be used.

A workarount for me is to unset http env variables:

For your env see: set|grep -i http

unset ...

Next step is to exlude localhost, 127.0.0.1

no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1
export no_proxy

It may be set in /etc/environment or /etc/bash.bashrc

Check this too. Don't forget to logout/in if you change things here.